# How can the transistor be in the cut-off region?

Tags: transistors, analog, bjt, npn

[image: This is question for your reference]

Imagine we have an NPN transistor and the base voltage Vb = 0V.  How can the transistor be in the cut-off region?

I've started by assuming it to be in the active region and then calculated the emitter voltage Ve = -0.7 by taking Vbe = 0.7.  In the book it was directly mentioned that the transistor is in the cut-off region.

I think I'm missing some concept. Can someone help me with this simple thing?

Comment: You need a positive voltage (more than 0.5V) between base and emitter to open the NPN transistor. Thus, If VB is 0V how can BJT be in the active region?

Comment: The rule of thumb that Vbe is about 0.7 volts only applies when the base-emitter junction is conducting "normal" amounts of current, usually something a milliamp or maybe a bit more or less. It's a very useful approximation. But, when the base voltage is zero, and the emitter voltage is zero, the base current is zero and you can't use the approximation.

Comment: You do not have a negative voltage source, so the emitter cannot be at a negative voltage.

Answer (score 8):

This is one of those cases where a teacher's desire to *"keep things simple"* instead turns into gross over-simplification that then just leads to confusion and disaster.

Let's focus on something else for a moment:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpH4Rc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Do you see anything in that circuit that goes outside the bounds of \$0\:\text{V}\to 6\:\text{V}\$? Is there anywhere, at all, that \$-0.7\:\text{V}\$ could arrive? Are you suggesting that the BJT itself, \$Q_1\$, might be able to ***generate*** it, somehow?

The answer is, of course, that there isn't a way for \$-0.7\:\text{V}\$ to show up in that schematic. You can't plug in a BJT and expect it to create a voltage that is outside its *world*. As you can see, it is nestled in a tiny world that lives between \$0\:\text{V}\$ and \$6\:\text{V}\$. There is no possibility for \$-0.7\:\text{V}\$.

As to the rest, once you accept that cannot happen then just ask yourself this question, *"If the base voltage is \$0\:\text{V}\$ and the other end of \$R_2\$ is also at \$0\:\text{V}\$, and if the emitter must be in between these two voltages, then what voltage is the emitter at?"*

It should be obvious.

Once you know the emitter voltage and also know the base voltage (which, by now, I'm sure you do) then you can see why the BJT is said to be in cut-off.

Yes?

Answer (score 5):

Well, can the emitter be at -0.7 V, based on the circuit you have it in? If not, then the assumption you started with must be false.

Hint: What were you measuring the base voltage relative to in the first place? Remember, a voltage measurement always represents the potential difference between two circuit nodes. The transistor is only "aware" of the voltages between its terminals.

Comment: Voltages are with respect to Ground

Comment: @AYUSHMEENA Ayush, I hope things are okay with you. You've not responded in a while. Best wishes.

Answer (score 4):

When Vb is equal to 0V, Vbe is equal also to 0V. With no voltage between base and emitter there can be no base current. Therefore the collector current is also 0mA. If there is no collector current then there can be no voltage drop across the collector's 10k resistor. Therefore both ends of the 10k resistor are at +6V and the transistor is operating in the cut-off region.

Answer (score 0):

> *I've started by assuming it to be in active region and then calculated
> Emitter Voltage Ve = -0.7 by taking Vbe = 0.7*

That's fine but, didn't your question title say this: -

> *How the Transistor is in Cut-off Region?*

And then you said this: -

> *then in the book it was directly mentioned that Transistor is in
> Cut-off Region*

So, why are you setting up the base-emitter voltage for the active region? Set base and emitter voltages to be the same (for example) for the cut-off region.

Comment: Actually this process or solution is mentioned in a book which confused me, thats why im asking

Comment: @AYUSHMEENA I'm really unsure what it is that you are actually asking.

Comment: actually the question is about When Vb = 0V find the Emitter current and Vc

Comment: Andy i've attached the question also please have a look

Comment: @AYUSHMEENA for the currents listed in answers (a), (b) and (c) which one satisfies the situation that makes Vbe 0 volts? Then, when you have decided which one, what will Vc be and does that selected answer also match that or, do you go for (d)?

Comment: Sorry Andy But answer is (c)

Comment: @AYUSHMEENA correct.

Comment: I think the process OP is following is to assume the transistor is in the active region and see if a contradiction arises (which should quickly become apparent).

Comment: @jcm you are reading this with the luxury of the OP having now revealed that he is trying to answer an exam-type question. I answered based on his question not containing that extra information. I was disadvantaged by the OP who later revealed what he was trying to solve.

Comment: @Andyaka sure, I wasn't criticising you or your answer, just trying to clarify OP's thought process.